# Import raster to postgis and add a foreign key constraint

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I use raster2pgsql to import raster files into a table with this command line:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>raster2pgsql -s 4326 -M -F -a c:\temp\mun.tif public.basqui_raster | psql -U postgres -d basqui -h localhost -p 5433
```

However I would like to add a foreign key constraint to each row during the import. Is it possible to do that when importing raster with raster2pgsql?

What could be the best way to do it?

Edit: I would prefer not use the filename (-F) in a second step to create the foreign key. I would prefer to do it during the import.